# How to do proper Git compatible hex sha packing/compression in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby, string, byte

I'm currently trying to port a ruby code to javascript. 
And i have this

```
ENTRY_FORMAT = "A7Z*H40"
mode = "100644"
fileName = "tree.js"
sha= "baae99010b237a699ff0aba02fd5310c18903b1b"
[mode, filename, sha].pack(ENTRY_FORMAT)
```

Where MODE, entry.name and entry.oid are string

• A7 :
this encodes the first string, MODE , as a seven-byte string padded on the right with spaces

• Z* : this encodes the second string, entry.name , as an arbitrary-length null-padded string, that
is, it represents the string as-is with a null byte appended to the end

•H40 :this encodes a string of forty hexadecimal digits, entry.oid , by packing each pair of
digits into a single byte as we saw in Section 2.3.3, “Trees on disk”

Can i do this in javaScript ?

Comment: Your Ruby code does not work, with lots of errors. The most important one is that `100644` is not a string, so not sure what kind of result you want. Please make sure your example is [example]

Comment: Sorry for that i don't run ruby on machine, the code is from a book so i didn't test it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you meant `mode` was also a string.

```js
let fileName = "file.js";
let sha = "baae99010b237a699ff0aba02fd5310c18903b1b";
let mode = '100664';

// encode all into bytes
let enc = new TextEncoder();
let modeArray = enc.encode(mode.padEnd(7));
let fileNameArray = enc.encode(fileName + '\0');
let shaArray = Uint8Array.from(sha.match(/../g), x => parseInt(x, 16));

// concatenate together
let array = new Uint8Array([...modeArray, ...fileNameArray, ...shaArray]);

console.log(array);
```

Node.js has `Buffer` class, which simplifies some of these operations:

```
let modeBuffer = Buffer.from(mode.padEnd(7));
let fileNameBuffer = Buffer.from(fileName + '\0');
let shaBuffer = Buffer.from(sha, 'hex');
let buffer = Buffer.concat([modeBuffer, fileNameBuffer, shaBuffer]);
// can fs.writeFile(file, buffer, ...)
```

Comment: It's good for me, as i want a string in the end it 's just miss const string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(array);. How can i learned do this myself, this process is called bitewise operation isn't it ?

Comment: No, what you're doing is UTF-8 encoding. Bitwise operations are `&`, `|` and `^`. However... why do you want a string in the end? What are you doing with it after? That is binary data, not text; text belong in a string, binary data in `Uint8Array`. It is very hard for me to come up with even one reason why you would want to turn it into a string.

Comment: I follow a book about git implementation in ruby. This part is for store the result of the commit command in ```.git/ ```. directory

Comment: Ah. I didn't see you are using Node; some of the above would be a bit simpler using `Buffer`. Still... Both [`fs.write`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) and [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) directly support `Buffer` and `Uint8Array`. Do not convert to string, it is an antipattern.

Comment: Ok i see but in the ruby code there is a class with  ```toString``` method. And there is some intermediate step that  happened before i actually writing to file. ```const str = object.toString()  the method is called here
    const content = `${object.type}${
      new TextEncoder().encode(str).length
    }\0${str}`;
    const shasum = crypto.createHash("sha1");
    shasum.update(content);
    object.oid = shasum.digest("hex");
    await this.writeObject(object.oid, content);  where i actually writing to file```

Comment: The fact that Ruby uses strings is irrelevant, you're writing JavaScript, not Ruby. The Ruby equivalent of `Buffer` or `Uint8Array` is a string with `ASCII-8BIT` encoding; so while Ruby uses strings for both text and binary data, JavaScript handles the former with strings, and the latter with typed arrays. Now, I don't know what `object` is in your code, nor what `writeObject` does... why don't you paste the original Ruby code into your question, so it's clear what you're asking? Because even if it is an intermediate step, still no reason to stringify. Also, updating the answer for Node.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215184/discussion-between-william-and-amadan).